# boto3 get_available_subresources method wrongly returns empty list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-vpc

Using the get_available_subresources method for a vpc with subresources(has multiple subnets and ec2 instances). Despite this it produces an empty list.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
#put id of vpc below
vpc = ec2.Vpc('vpc-...')
print(ec2.Vpc(vpc).get_available_subresources())
```

method in question: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/vpc/get_available_subresources.html

Comment: EC2 instances and subnets are not "subresources" of a vpc. If you want all ec2 instances in a vpc, have to query ec2 instances with filters.

Comment: what would qualify as a subresource?

Comment: The documentation is very weak here. Some poking around suggests that numerous boto3 resources declare this same method, all are documented identically, and what, if anything, is returned depends on the resource in question. The [source code](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/3c988a24f22795d3cb9cf26a74c085d2e6a58504/boto3/resources/factory.py#L257C11-L259C70) suggests that subresources relate to resources that share identifiers/data with a given resource and gives the example of S3 objects as subresources of S3 buckets.